# PHP: How can I print multi-dimensional array elements using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

```
$shop = array( 
                array("Rose", 1.25 , 15),
                array("Daisy", 0.75 , 25),
                array("Orchid", 1.15 , 7)
            );


    for($i = 0; $i <= count($shop); $i++){
        foreach($shop[$i] as $key => $val)
            echo $key . ' = ' . $val . '<br>';
    }
```

So this is the output I'm getting:

0 = Rose

1 = 1.25

2 = 15

0 = Daisy

1 = 0.75

2 = 25

0 = Orchid

1 = 1.15

2 = 7

============================================

But then I get an error:

**Warning**: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

What I want to know is how to correct this, and if there's a more efficient way to write what I'm trying to output?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, your using `<=` instead of `<`. So your for loop goes one step to far and the array is out of bounds.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($shop); $i++){
    foreach($shop[$i] as $key => $val)
        echo $key . ' = ' . $val . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: or 2 foreach rather than the for

Comment: I feel dumb. Thanks budd!

Comment: No need to - sometimes one doesn't see the obvious

Answer (score 1):

When iterating through an array, always use a `foreach` instead of a `for` loop.

```
foreach ($shop as $foo) {
    foreach ($foo as $key => $val) {
        echo $key . ' = ' . $val . '<br />';
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($Array AS $Values){
    if (is_array($Values)){
        foreach ($Values AS $Inner){
            echo $Inner;
        }
    }else{
        echo $Values;
    }
}
```

I Personally would go for 2 foreach loops. Check if the value passed is an array, if it is. Step in. If not, print the value