# How to print complicated multidimensional array through foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an Multi Dimensional array like below.

```
<?php$array = Array ( [ResultIndex] => OB4 [Source] => 3 [IsLCC] => 1 [IsRefundable] => [GSTAllowed] => [AirlineRemark] => this is a test from aditya [Fare] => Array ( [Currency] => INR [BaseFare] => 865 [Tax] => 613 [TaxBreakup] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => YQTax [value] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [key] => YR [value] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [key] => PSF [value] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [key] => UDF [value] => 0 ) [4] => Array ( [key] => JNTax [value] => 52 ) [5] => Array ( [key] => INTax [value] => 0 ) [6] => Array ( [key] => TransactionFee [value] => 0 ) [7] => Array ( [key] => OtherTaxes [value] => 0 ) ) [YQTax] => 0 [AdditionalTxnFeeOfrd] => 0 [AdditionalTxnFeePub] => 0 [PGCharge] => 0 [OtherCharges] => 0 [ChargeBU] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => TBOMARKUP [value] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [key] => CONVENIENCECHARGE [value] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [key] => OTHERCHARGE [value] => 0 ) ) [Discount] => 0 [PublishedFare] => 1478 [CommissionEarned] => 22.06 [PLBEarned] => 14.09 [IncentiveEarned] => 14.33 [OfferedFare] => 1427.52 [TdsOnCommission] => 4.41 [TdsOnPLB] => 2.82 [TdsOnIncentive] => 2.87 [ServiceFee] => 0 [TotalBaggageCharges] => 0 [TotalMealCharges] => 0 [TotalSeatCharges] => 0 [TotalSpecialServiceCharges] => 0 ) [FareBreakdown] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Currency] => INR [PassengerType] => 1 [PassengerCount] => 1 [BaseFare] => 865 [Tax] => 613 [YQTax] => 0 [AdditionalTxnFeeOfrd] => 0 [AdditionalTxnFeePub] => 0 [PGCharge] => 0 ) ) [Segments] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Baggage] => 10 Kg [CabinBaggage] => 7 Kg [TripIndicator] => 1 [SegmentIndicator] => 1 [Airline] => Array ( [AirlineCode] => SG [AirlineName] => SpiceJet [FlightNumber] => 1033 [FareClass] => C [OperatingCarrier] => ) [NoOfSeatAvailable] => 4 [Origin] => Array ( [Airport] => Array ( [AirportCode] => BLR [AirportName] => Hindustan [Terminal] => [CityCode] => BLR [CityName] => Bangalore [CountryCode] => IN [CountryName] => India ) [DepTime] => 2017-10-21T17:40:00 ) [Destination] => Array ( [Airport] => Array ( [AirportCode] => MAA [AirportName] => Chennai [Terminal] => [CityCode] => MAA [CityName] => Chennai [CountryCode] => IN [CountryName] => India ) [ArrTime] => 2017-10-21T18:40:00 ) [Duration] => 60 [GroundTime] => 0 [Mile] => 0 [StopOver] => [StopPoint] => [StopPointArrivalTime] => 2017-10-21T18:40:00 [StopPointDepartureTime] => 2017-10-21T17:40:00 [Craft] => DH8 [Remark] => [IsETicketEligible] => 1 [FlightStatus] => Confirmed [Status] => ) ) ) [LastTicketDate] => [TicketAdvisory] => [FareRules] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Origin] => BLR [Destination] => MAA [Airline] => SG [FareBasisCode] => CSAVER [FareRuleDetail] => [FareRestriction] => ) ) [AirlineCode] => SG [ValidatingAirline] => SG );?>
```

how to make it print using foreach loop in php. if any one have idea to rectify this please suggest me

Comment: Pls first look trough so, this was asked so many times like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651864/how-to-print-multidimensional-arrays-in-php or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161077/php-how-can-i-print-multi-dimensional-array-elements-using-foreach

Comment: do you know how to write foreach ?

Comment: It's very hard to see the array when it's printed in one line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print multidimensional arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651864/how-to-print-multidimensional-arrays-in-php)